# printing words consecutively reverse and same order?

Tags: java

Assignment:

> Write a program to show the output like this where input is given at run time.

Sample input:

```
my name is raghavendra
```

Sample Output:

```
ym name si raghavendra
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.*;

class ReverseString2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new
```

Comment: this is how NOT to ask a question!!

Comment: Please properly format your question and show what you have tried that is not working

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, I would use a `StringBuilder`. Because, when the index is even it has an useful [`reverse()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#reverse%28%29) function. I believe you wanted something like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = sc.nextLine();
        // The \\s+ pattern matches one or more white-space characters.
        String[] words = line.split("\\s+");
        for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            if (i != 0) {
                System.out.print(' ');
            }
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(words[i]);
            // Reverse every other word.
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                sb.reverse();
            }
            System.out.print(sb);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to use `charAt`. The code would look something similar to this:

```
public String invertEvenWords(String line) {     

    String result = "";
    String[] words = line.split("\\s+");

    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {

        /* The n-th word is reversed if n i even. */
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            String inv = "";
            for (int j = 0; j < words[i].length(); j++) {
                char ch = words[i].charAt(j);
                inv = ch + inv;
            }
            result += inv + " ";

        /* Otherwise the word isn't reversed. */
        } else {
            result += words[i] + " ";
        }
    }

    return result;

}
```